# Java natural cross join array list

Tags: java, arrays

I have this array list in java

```
1   B0  C5  CAR AM
2   D0  C5  CAR AM
3   A0  C5  CAR AM
10  N0  C5  CAR AM
16  T0  C5  CAR AM
33  AG  C5  CAR AM
50  FD  C5  CAR AM
```

i want to produce the below results in a new arraylist

```
1   B0  C5  CAR AM 1 B0
2   D0  C5  CAR AM 1 B0
3   A0  C5  CAR AM 1 B0
10  N0  C5  CAR AM 1 B0
16  T0  C5  CAR AM 1 B0
33  AG  C5  CAR AM 1 B0
50  FD  C5  CAR AM 1 B0
1   B0  C5  CAR AM 2 D0
2   D0  C5  CAR AM 2 D0
3   A0  C5  CAR AM 2 D0
10  N0  C5  CAR AM 2 D0
16  T0  C5  CAR AM 2 D0
33  AG  C5  CAR AM 2 D0
50  FD  C5  CAR AM 2 D0
........
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Please explain how the second array is derived from the first.

Comment: There is no question whatsoever but for the examples it seems that you may need a couple of foor loops with a count variable to begin with. Can you show us what have you done so far?

Comment: hi OldCurmudgeon, the second array contains the values of the first array with additional first and second column repeated 7 times for every column 1 and two in the first array

Comment: I have created the list that returns the first array from my db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get a multiple of the array.
This is how you can do it:

```
String[] mult(String[] base, int numBy) {
  String[] res = new String();
  for(int i = 0; i<numBy;i++) {

      String[] tmp = new String[res.length];
      System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, res, 0, res.length);

      res = new String[res.length + base.length];
      System.arraycopy(res, 0, tmp, 0, tmp.length);
      System.arraycopy(res,tmp.length,base,0,base.length);

  }
     return res;
}
```

Comment: yes but they should be object array please check how array 2 is derived from array 1

Comment: Map<String, List<CsvDefaultFilesViewDto>> map = new HashMap<String, List<CsvDefaultFilesViewDto>>();
 
  List<CsvDefaultFilesViewDto> newList = new ArrayList<CsvDefaultFilesViewDto>();
 
 List<CsvDefaultFilesViewDto> defaultFiles = build();
 
 for(CsvDefaultFilesViewDto data : defaultFiles){
  
  
 }//I am trying to put the values in a map but i am stuck here